# How is an object created and initialized in a method declaration in Java

Tags: java, methods, return, parameter-passing

I'd just started learning about passing information to methods and constructors in Java when I ran into this
`public Polygon polygonFrom(Point[] corners){...`
How is the **Polygon** object created in the method declaration? Is it the **return** type and how?

Comment: That is a regular method that returns a `Polygon` instance. You can probably take a look at the source code somewhere.

Comment: That depends on what the Polygon object constructor is. If it takes and array of Points then `return new Polygon(corners);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically methods have to following structure

```
[visibility] [return type] [name] ([argument1 type] [argument1 name], ...) {

 [method body]

}
```

for your example this means: Yes, Polygon is the return type of your method "polygonFrom". How this object is created is completely up to you. You could just call
`return new Polygon()` (maybe with constructor parameters).
But in general that is exactly the purpose of a method to create this Polygon anyhow to not repeat this everytime you need to access a Polygon this way.